# Using Python to read multiple JSON files

Tags: python, json

With the following connections I am trying to get info from multiple(2) files. both of these files are in json format. The problem occurs at close time, When I say json_data.close(), it closes both connections. It support for close one connection as I have indented the second connection.

please help, new to python and json

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('/tmp/AutoScale.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

for i in range(len(data["AutoScalingGroups"])):
    pprint(data["AutoScalingGroups"][i]["LaunchConfigurationName"])

#Second Connection

    json_data=open('/tmp/launchConfig.json')
    data = json.load(json_data)
    pprint(data["LaunchConfigurations"][i]["LaunchConfigurationName"])
    json_data.close()      # closed first connection
json_data.close()          # closed second connection
```

Comment: It never closes the first file (`/tmp/AutoScale.json`) because you overwrite `json_data` in the loop. Read up on python's scoping [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: You need to use a different file descriptor when opening different files.

Comment: can you guys post a sample code for file descriptor and having NESTED LOOP IS INTENTIONAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reassign json_data in the for loop, the original file object is lost (actually, it loses all references and closes the file as python destroys it). If you want to keep it around for some reason, you need to use a different variable in the for loop.

Here, I've renamed the inner variables. There are better ways to load the file (e.g., use a with clause, just do `data = json.load(open('/tmp/AutoScale.json'))`, etc... but you get the idea.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('/tmp/AutoScale.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

for i in range(len(data["AutoScalingGroups"])):
    pprint(data["AutoScalingGroups"][i]["LaunchConfigurationName"])
    json_data_2=open('/tmp/launchConfig.json')
    data_2 = json.load(json_data_2)
    pprint(data_2["LaunchConfigurations"][i]["LaunchConfigurationName"])
    json_data_2.close()      # closed second file
json_data.close()          # closed first file
```